# Dividing percentage variable in Sass?

Tags: sass

I have a variable which is a number and a % eg 10%. How can I use it as a value in my SASS but apply a division on it?

I have this:

```
$value: 0.1;

$value-percent: $value * 1%;

$value-from-50: (50 - $value) * 1%;

    .test {
        padding-left: $value-percent;
    }

    .test2 {
        width: $value-from-50;
    }
```

Which outputs this:

```
    .test {
        padding-left: 10%;
    }

    .test2 {
        width: 40%;
    }
```

What I now need to do is apply half of the value of $value-percent:

```
    .test3 {
        padding-left: $value-percent / 2;
    }
```

So that I can output:

```
    .test3 {
        width: 5%;
    }
```

Ive tried various combinations of that example code with normal and curly brackets. I can get the correct number of 10 outputted into the CSS but the % is always missing from it.

Comment: There is not enough information here to reproduce the problem.  What you've posted here should give you your desired output.

Comment: Make sure the contents of `$var` has a percentage sign.

Comment: I still cannot reproduce a problem.  The first selector has a padding left of 0.1%, the second has a width of 49.9%, and the third has a padding-left of 0.05%.

Answer (score 1):

If your initial var isn't a percentage and is just a number you may need to try this:

```
.test {
    padding-right: ($var / 2) + 0%
}
```

Which is better practice as it'll convert the value you pass it into what you're adding it to, in this case a percentage.

Comment: Based on the output provided, why would you think `$var` contains something other than a percentage?

Comment: Because they have not showed $var defined. Which is why I said IF.

Comment: Don't answer questions if not all of the information is provided.